# Flutter CupertinoContextMenu actions buttons not aligned center

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list view with horizontal scroll and i have added CupertinoContextMenu to the image.
everything is works fine but the action buttons are not aligned center.

I have added the code. I tried with wrap scaffold too. same issue still.

I have to align the action buttons under the image center posisiton.

```
 Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Center(child: _invoiceImageSlider()),
);

    // Image Slider List
  Widget _invoiceImageSlider(){
    return Container(
      height: 250,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
      child: ListView(
        // This next line does the trick.
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 160.0,
            child: _invoiceContextMenu(),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 160.0,
            child: _invoiceContextMenu(),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 160.0,
            child: _invoiceContextMenu(),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 160.0,
            child: _invoiceContextMenu(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _invoiceContextMenu(){
    return Container(
      child: CupertinoContextMenu(
        child: Container(
          child: _invoiceImage(),
        ),
        previewBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Widget child) {
          return FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,               
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(64.0 * animation.value),
              child: Image.asset('assets/invoices/'+_invoiceInfo.filename),
            ),
          );
        },
        actions: <Widget>[
          CupertinoContextMenuAction(
            child:  Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Feather.trash_2,
                    size: 25,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Text("Delete")
                ]
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by centering the whole ContextMenu like this:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: CupertinoContextMenu(),
)
```

Hope this helped. Cheers

Comment: this does not work for me, behaves exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** in your case, you can't! action menu will be centered only if your widget is "almost centered"

**Solution:** copy `CupertinoContextMenu` and edit `_contextMenuLocation` function (read below to understand)

**Long answer:** action menu position depend on origin position of widget

**How it work:**

- Split screen to 2 part from center (left side & right side)

1. **Center case:** If widget is overlap on both left and right sides, and the overlap part in left side or right side has width at least <= 1/4 widget.width
2. **Left case:** Else, if widget.dx in left side
3. **Right case** Else, if widget.dx in right side

Check this code (in `CupertinoContextMenu` class) to understand the logic above

```
_ContextMenuLocation get _contextMenuLocation {

 final Rect childRect = _getRect(_childGlobalKey);
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;

    final double center = screenWidth / 2;
    final bool centerDividesChild = childRect.left < center
      && childRect.right > center;
    final double distanceFromCenter = (center - childRect.center.dx).abs();
    if (centerDividesChild && distanceFromCenter <= childRect.width / 4) {
      return _ContextMenuLocation.center;
    }

    if (childRect.center.dx > center) {
      return _ContextMenuLocation.right;
    }

return _ContextMenuLocation.left;
```

}

[image]